# Does FxCop in C# cover MISRA?

Tags: c#, misra

For programs written in .net/C# does FxCop (and Roslyn equivalents) cover the relevant rules in MISRA? Has anybody gone through and ticked them off?

Or is there a compliance standard for .NET similar to MISRA?

Comment: MISRA is a coding standard for C programs, it does not and cannot apply to C# code.  Nor does it have to, C# simply does not nearly have the same kind of problems as C.  You'd better talk to your customer, they may outlaw a .NET program or want a C# program to be validated a very different way.

Comment: There is also a MISRA standard for C++. But I doubt there will ever be one for C#, since C# is very unsuitable for mission-critical software. Closest thing so far I would guess is the CERT Java standard... but I haven't read that one.

Comment: I was not looking for complete coverage but there are a some rules in MISRA that helps to keep clean practices. After some googling I did find http://www.sonarlint.org/ which nicely categorises its Roslyn analyzers (one of them being MISRA)

Answer (score 0):

No. By default FxCop (now Code Analysis in Visual Studio) only watches for spelling/casing corrections and Microsoft's own guidelines. You are free to come-up with your own rules, of course.

Note that most of the static-analysis tools only look at the compiled CIL - so you won't be able to watch for safety-critical style violations (such as non-braced `if` and unintentional `switch`-case fallthroughs).

Given that MISRA is specifically for C and C++ (and not C#/CIL) you won't find it under FxCop. Though I imagine if you did implement MISRA for C# you would make a tidy bit of money from it - I'd pay for it!

Comment: Now with roslyn both the syntax and semantic models are available in to the analysers. Even before VS2015 we had the "must have default switch case" in a StyleCop customisation.

Answer (score 0):

After some googleing I did find http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/rules/index.html#sonarLintVersion=2.0.0&ruleId=S2291&tags=misra

This tool looks quite interesting taking the Roslyn analyzers to the next level. I will investigate this tool further.